# How to speed up Typekit loading

Tags: css, fonts, adobe, typeface, typekit

Has anyone else found it really frustrating when you reload a page and Typekit takes half a second to catch up to the rest of the page.

[Before loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqUmG.png) and [after loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWNyS.png). I do understand that using a condensed typeface here isn't helping my case, but you know.. it suits the brand.

Comment: I assume you've told typekit to use caching (https://blog.typekit.com/2016/01/21/improved-caching-for-kits-opt-for-longer-cache-timeout/), and made sure to load the typekit script *early* (but still async), rather than "at the end of the body". You want to kick off the script load right after the title, with an `async` keyword in the script tag.

Comment: Mike, thanks for your reply. I'll read through the blog post and it has cached now!

Answer (score -1):

By default the kit settings are `async: true`,
Change it to `async: false`

See the below example codes.

```
(function(d) {
        var config = {
            kitId: '', // Your kit id
            scriptTimeout: 3000,
            async: true
          },
          h = d.documentElement,
          t = setTimeout(function() {
            h.className = h.className.replace(/\bwf-loading\b/g, '') + ' wf-inactive';
          }, config.scriptTimeout),
          tk = d.createElement('script'),
          f = false,
          s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
          a;
        h.className += ' wf-loading';
        tk.src = 'https://use.typekit.net/' + config.kitId + '.js';
        tk.async = false;
        tk.onload = tk.onreadystatechange = function() {
          a = this.readyState;
          if (f || (a && a != 'complete' && a != 'loaded')) return;
          f = true;
          clearTimeout(t);
          try {
            Typekit.load(config);
          } catch (e) {}
        };
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(tk, s);
      })(document);
```

This will stop the fonts rendering until they are downloaded and ready for use.